# New-Item IIS:\Sites\SiteName - Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: powershell

I created a function to create a site in IIS, but I"m running into a bizzare error.

Here's the url I've been using as a reference:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/433/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools/

New-Item : Index was outside the bounds of the array.

At line:1 char:9
+ New-Item <<<<   'IIS:\Sites\SiteName' -physicalPath "$sitePath" -bindings @{protocol="$protocol";bindingInformation="$fullBindings"}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Here's the code block that calls the function:

```
    function Create-FullSite($site, $framework, $userName, $password, $protocol, $port, $enabledProtocols)
            {
                #Write-Host "Prompting for path to "
                $sitePath = Select-Folder

                #Write-Host $sitePath

                #Write-Host "Setting up app pool for "
                $csServicePool = New-Item -Path iis:\AppPools\$site

                #Write-Host "Configuring app pool"
                Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\$site -name managedRuntimeVersion -value $framework
                $csServicePool.processModel.username = $userName
                $csServicePool.processModel.password = $password
                $csServicePool.processModel.identityType = 3
                $csServicePool  | set-item 

                #Write-Host "Creating IIS Site "

                $fullBindings = ':'+$port.ToString()+':'
                Write-Host $fullBindings

                Write-Host $site    
                Write-Host $sitePath
                Write-Host $protocol

                New-Item IIS:\Sites\$site -physicalPath "$sitePath" -bindings @{protocol="$protocol";bindingInformation="$fullBindings"}

                #Write-Host "Assigning App pool to "



                Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\$site -name ApplicationPool -value $site

                #Write-Host "setting applicationDefaults.enabledProtocols: "
                Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\$site -name applicationDefaults.enabledProtocols -value "$enabledProtocols"

                return $sitePath
            }   

    $ServicesSiteName = 'MyNewSite'
            $ServicesPort = '80'
            $ServiceBindings = 'http'

            $csWebServiceUserName = 'domain\someUser'
            $csWebServicePassword = 'AReallyComplexPassword'

            $v2Framework = 'v2.0'
            $v4Framework = 'v4.0'

           Create-FullSite $ServicesSiteName $v2Framework $csWebServiceUserName $csWebServicePassword $ServiceBindings $ServicesPort $ServiceBindings
```

Comment: It turns out if you delete all the websites and app pools in IIS, the "Index Out of Range" exception is always thrown.  I have a feeling it's trying to generate a site id and cannot find the next one in the list.

This article helped me solve the issue.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1159761.aspx

Comment: You should stick that comment in an actual answer to make it easier for other people to find.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It turns out if you delete all the websites in IIS, the "Index Out of Range" exception is always thrown. I have a feeling it's trying to generate a site id and cannot find the next one in the list. This article helped me solve the issue. http://forums.iis.net/t/1159761.aspx